# I can't get the values using NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, nsxmlparser

I tried many methods to get the values of NSXMLParser, but I didn't succeed.
attributeDict objectForKey is not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
    - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
 { 
  if (![elementName isEqual:@"item"])
    return;

CerereIndemnizatieDoc *cerereIndemnizatie  = [[CerereIndemnizatieDoc alloc] init];
NSString * index = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString * name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"nume"];
cerereIndemnizatie.id = index;
cerereIndemnizatie.nume = name;

if (!cereriIndemnizatie)
    cereriIndemnizatie = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[cereriIndemnizatie addObject:cerereIndemnizatie];
```

}

Comment: please post your xml structure

Comment: Why are you replacing the `cereriIndemnizatie` object with a `NSMutableArray` in this line: `if (!cereriIndemnizatie)
    cereriIndemnizatie = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` since you replace the object `cerereIndemnizatie` you won't be able to add it.

Comment: Midhun MP I can't post the xml structure. it can't be seen. How should I do this?

Comment: @rckoenes: I saw that too, but it's not the same object. Variable names are different by 1 character (cerere... vs cereri...).

Comment: @alin: you should atleast have some kind of template or test data that you are using to build this.  In my experience, you have to know quite a bit about the XML you are trying to parse when you use an NSXMLParser to do it.  I imagine the code you have here will work if your XML is set up in a certain way, but since you are saying it's not working, I'm guess that isn't the way it's set up.  Without knowing how the XML is set up, we can't really suggest what you need to change to make it work.

Comment: I solved the problem. I retrieved the values in didEndElement and now it works. Thank you all for your help.